# verilog counter implementation unexpected behaviour

Tags: counter, verilog, hdl

I made a counter in verilog and realized it in hardware. But I am unable to explain the behaviour The code is:

```
module clock_test(clk_in,led,rst);
input wire clk_in;
input wire rst;
output wire [7:0] led;

reg [23:0] counter = 24'b0;

assign led = counter[23:16];

always @(posedge clk_int)  begin
    if(rst) begin
     counter <= 0;
  end
else begin
     counter <= counter +1;
   end
 end
 endmodule // clock_test
```

In the hardware, when I hit `rst`, the LEDs freeze at the point it was counting. Its not becoming exactly zero. Assert `rst`, and you can see some random pattern other than zero, which dont change unless I release `rst`.

My question is : when `if(rst) begin` block executes, `counter` is set to 0. Since leds are assigned as combo logic from `counter`, should'nt it reflect immediately ?

Comment: Is the counter working correctly when `rst` is low? The clock on the always block is incorrect. Should be `clk_in`, not `clk_int`.

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo, and i acutally got it to work and and my concern is the behaviour in the hadware :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a synchronous reset the reset value would not take effect until the next clock edge after reset asserts.

When you assert reset does that also stop the clock?  That would seem to be the most likely cause since otherwise your code looks correct (excepting the syntax error noted by Greg).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the clk is typod and it was a sync reset, rather than an async.

Try this :

```
module clock_test(
  input        clk_in,
  input        rst,
  output [7:0] led
);

reg [23:0] counter;

assign led = counter[23:16];

always @(posedge clk_in or posedge rst)  begin
  if(rst) begin
    counter <= 0;
  end
  else begin
    counter <= counter +1;
  end
 end
 endmodule // clock_test
```

NB: you are using an active high reset (1 implies reset). If you are actually using active low (0 applies reset) the you need to change the following:

```
always @(posedge clk_in or negedge rst)  begin
  if(~rst) begin
    counter <= 0;
```

Comment: Making it asynchronous did the trick!  Thank you very much @Munkymorgy and @BrianMagnuson, All your assumptions were correct, The design actually stopped clk from a Digital Clock Management Tile DCM_SP instance (Xilinx FPGA Specific), because rst was connected to DCM_SP`s reset input too!  I actually stripped off some Xilinx FPGA specifc code from it. Here is the full version : http://pastebin.com/NZXcEyxj Thank you all again! :)

Comment: No problem, Jay as you are new to StackOverflow might I suggest that if you have got a correct answer you should accept it. Might I suggest Brian Magnusons as he was first. upvotes for the other would be gladly accepted.